# How to convert an array json to Tree of objects in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I would like to convert an json to tree of objects.
For example

```
    {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "BEAUTY",
    "description": "",
    "parent_id": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "SunGlass",
    "description": "",
    "parent_id": 2,
  },
     {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Shirts",
    "description": "",
    "parent_id": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 41,
    "label": "black Glasses",
    "description": "electronique",
    "parent_id": 5,
  },
    {
    "id": 34,
    "label": "T-shirts",
    "description": "electronique",
    "parent_id": 6,
  },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "Phones",
    "description": "",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "embedded_parent": null,
  }
```

What I want is to convert this list to a tree object based on label attribute,Like this result :

```
const TREE_DATA = {
  BEAUTY: {
    'SunGlass': {'black Glasses':null},
    'Shirts': null,
    
  },
  Phones: {
      'Sbardilate': null,
      'T-shirts': null,
      'Balons': null,
  },
  
};
```

I need a recursive function to make this result,to pass this result to my component widget in angular.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What you're asking doesn't seem specific to Angular or TypeScript at all.

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe for not explaining well , What I want exactly is to convert the my json list to Tree Format that I specified

Comment: That part is clear, but note that SO isn't a code-writing service - where is your attempt to make that happen? In terms of TS/Angular they simply don't seem relevant, this is just a regular JS task.

Comment: Because in final result I had a function tha t build a tree componant , but I need to give it the Tree object TREE_DATA  , In my example i write it manually , but I build it dynamically based on json data

Comment: If you have any idea about how to do this task js , it will help me a lot , because I don't have a solid background in JS

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, you should always provide your solution. Show us what you have done and where exactly you are stuck. It won't help you to just copy and paste solutions from StackOverflow.

For your exact problem I give you some hints. First create some Interfaces that makes the development easier. For the Node you can define a recursive interface as follows:

```
interface Item {
  id: number,
  label: string,
  parent_id: number,
  description: string
}

interface Node {
  [label: string]: Node | null;
}
```

The next thing you should do is to group your elements by the `parent_id`. This enables you to quickly access all of the information in one Node by doing `groupedByParentId[id]` with an access time of O(1).

```
const groupedByParentId = array.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    const parentId = cur.parentId;
    const groupedItems = acc[parentId] == [];
    return {...acc, [parentId]: [...groupedItems, cur]}
  },
  {} as {[id: string]: Item[]}
);
```

Defining a function for having a starting point for your tree root is a good idea as well:

```
const rootNodeId = 0;
function makeTree(): Node {
  const node = makeNode(rootNodeId);
  return node;
}
```

Then only the `makeNode` function is left. Since you haven't tried anything on your own yet, I won't provide the full solution, but here are some hints so that you can proceed hopefully easily:

- The functions API is `makeNode(id: number)` and it returns a `Node`
- Get the children of the current node with above data structure
- If there are no children, you already know what to return ;)
- If there are children, *make a node* for each of them and store the node in a property defined by the `label`
- Finally return the node

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Felix , I will apply this hints